# How to map translated variable names for column names, so I can export them?

Tags: design, c#, generic-programming

In short story, I want to make some universal generators for different formats (CSV, XLS, XLSX and JSON for now). Just to be clear, I will make different classes for all formats.

I have different models, with different fields. For example:

```
 public class Agents 
 {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }   
        public string Email {get;set;}   
 }

 public class IdCards 
 {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int MaleTotal { get; set; } 
        public int FemaleTotal { get; set; }       
 }
```

And I want to get tables that look like this for english:

`Agent`:

```
|Name |Email           |
| --- | ---            |
| Sta |sta@example.com |
|Danny|dany@example.com|
|Elle |elle@example.com|
```

`IdCards`:

```
|Men|Women|
|---|---  |
|12 |13   |
|11 |14   |
|120|111  |
```

and for french:

`Agent`:

```
|Nom  |E-mail          |
| --- | ---            |
| Sta |sta@example.com |
|Danny|dany@example.com|
|Elle |elle@example.com|
```

`IdCards`:

```
|Hommes|Femmes|
| --- | ---   |
|12   |13     |
|11   |14     |
|120  |111    |
```

Question is, how to prepare this models so I can get variable name as a column name?

Comment: This sounds like a maintenance nightmare. If at all possible, keep field names in your data schema constant and use an I18N framework to localize displayed values where necessary. There is already a near-infinite number of solutions to this problem, do **not** roll our own.

Comment: @KilianFoth Can you suggest me some of these solutions?

Comment: This would not be a task for "generic programming". It should be possible with reflection and attributes, i.e. use reflection to list properties, and use attributes to either list translated names, or a key to a translation dictionary. But you should absolutely not translate names for something that is intended to be machine readable, i.e. json, and possibly csv.

Comment: I am new to this, why I should not translate these property names? I mean, it is same in json if it is called "name" or "nom" @JonasH

Comment: Because it is generally assumed that a file saved on a computer using French can be opened on one using German. And even if *you* handle this issue, if anyone else parse your json files, they will most likely not take into account that there is one version per language. Json is not meant to be read by users. And computers do not care if it says "name" or "nom", but inconsistency will make everything terribly more complicated.

Comment: What is the purpose of those "tables"? Are those just reports, to be read by humans? Or do you want to use them as a storage media (so they can be read by a program froms disk at a later point in time)? For humans, translation is fine (and a trivial programming task, for which we don't answer questions on this site). For programs, it makes things unnecessary complicated.

Comment: @DocBrown, I partially disagree with *"For programs, [translation] makes things unnecessarily complicated"*. So much of the software development world is in English, and so much of the world doesn't speak English as a primary language. From the perspective of a French-speaking developer, it is easier to reason about the code seeing `foo = bar["Nom"]`. Although you could just as easily do `string Nom = "Name"` and use `bar[Nom]` later on in your code. So I also partially agree with your sentiment.

Comment: @GregBurghardt: you talk about the perspective of developers = humans. I talk about the perspective of programs. And using a localized **storage format** is really nonsensical and error prone, this would lead to code who has to try out `foo=bar["Nom"]`, `foo=bar["Name"]` and maybe `foo=bar["Nombre"]` all after another until one fits.

Comment: @DocBrown: and that is why I partially agree with you. At the same time, though, it is hard for me to separate "programs" from "humans" because (as of 2022) humans write programs. Of course, when [HAL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAL_9000) comes for our jobs, this becomes HAL's problem...